# DSM unaccessible via browser since update to 6.2.3

Tags: nas, synology

Since I upgraded my DSM from version 4 to version 6.2.3, I can't access DSM interface via browser. I see my Syno (413J) in the Synology assistant and I can access my data via the finder.

Performed twice a configuration reset, tried static IP, and DHCP, tried :5000 and https port 5001

Not accessible via PC or Mac or android.

Error Message in Chrome:

This site can’t be reached x.x.x.x refused to connect. Try:

Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I am out of idea now :/t